# How to clear Excel filters using Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to clear all the filter from an excel file using Java (or Groovy), but I didn't find any solution using autoFilter.
Just a little explanation about the flow: I'm downloading an excel file from a web application, then I need to verify some information presented on that, the problem is that the file comes with filters already set and due to this the filters need to be cleared before we start the validations (This is being done on Katalon Studio using Java/Groovy).
I've tried some methods in WorkBook and Sheet, but didn't succeed.
Adding the libraries I'm using as suggested:

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java (the language, and the core libraries; the ones that start with `java.*` cannot read excel sheets, at all. You are using a library to read them. There are many such libraries. You'd have to edit your question and include the library you have, and preferably some snippets of code on how you load the excel sheet in. For example, "I use Apache POI".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've added the libs as suggested. It is Apache POI btw :)

Comment: "Java (the language, and the core libraries; the ones that start with java.* cannot read excel sheets, at all. " - I don't think that is correct.  You can read any type of file you like using only core libraries.

Comment: Hi @JeffScottBrown, if you have any tips regarding the issue as well, please share :)
Also, share these libs if possible!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an autofilter feature that might work like so:

http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Autofilter

Comment: Agree, but as long as we have a way to set filters, we should have a way to clear them also, right?

Comment: Who says POI can set filters? It can neither set nor clear them. Yes, I wish it were a full Excel clone.

Comment: I saw some topics here about Auto Filter, is it not the same?

Comment: My apologies. You seem to be right here. There is something about AutoFilter but I have not tried it. http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Autofilter